# Text inside td not utilizing entire cell width

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem which I can't seem to figure out. I have a `td` showing some timestamp text inside it. The strange thing is that this text would rather use multiple lines than use the whole cell width available to it before moving to the next line. There's ample width available, so how do I make the timestamp text fit in just one line ?

[image]

The CSS currently being applied to the `td` is the following:

```
width: 30%;
word-wrap: break-word;
white-space: pre-wrap;
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
white-space: -pre-wrap;
text-align: center;
```

Note that the `width` properly above is being used to set the width of the `td` relative to the entire table width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of your `<div>` child element of the `<td>` is getting set to 30% of the width of the cell and not the table. Try setting the `width` to `100%` in the `splunk-timedata-field` class.

Answer (score 0):

The css you give is applied on the div instead of the td.
So this div width is 30%, and then your text breaks.

You may have another unrelated error, the "==$0" string that is showing just after the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove class  from div and set this class to td.
Then width 30% will work for total width of table.